# How to remove delimiters when reading csv file in Python?

Tags: python, csv

Just trying to learn python and trying to help a friend with taking a column from a .csv file to print it with a label-maker. The first problem I came across is this:

I will use this example file: test.csv

```
1111,2222,3333,4444
aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd
aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd
```

I run it trough:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_File:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_File)

with open('test2.csv', 'w') as new_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        (csv_writer).writerow(line[1])
```

and get the output:

```
2,2,2,2
b,b,b,b
b,b,b,b
```

I want the output:

```
2222
bbbb
bbbb
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a simple but not bad question, ref, https://realpython.com/python-csv/#parsing-csv-files-with-pythons-built-in-csv-library

Answer (score 1):

`writerow` is expecting a whole list to write as a row, just as you got a whole list from the reader. To output one field only you should wrap it in a list:

```
csv_writer.writerow([line[1]])
```

But note it would be simpler to just write the data directly, since you don't need any of the functionality that the CSV writer gives you:

```
with open('test2.csv', 'w') as new_file:
    for line in csv_reader:
        new_file.write(line[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

`writerow` takes a iterable of data of one row.  You provide it a single string that gets interpreted as iterable and each element gets printed as column.

Fix:

```
csv_writer.writerow([line[1]])  # put the string into a list so you provide a single item row
```